# Getting the sum of an excel column without getting subformula using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I was wondering if I can get the sum of an excel column, without getting the **subformula** for each item category(**Tort and nach**).

Take note that there are times there will be an additional item and will be added to the category; meaning I cannot specify the cell value (e.g, SUM(G12:G18) + SUM(G21:G26)).
Is there any way to do this using PHP Excel?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try: =SUM(G12:G18,G21:G26)

I have a diffent excel language, where I have to use a semi-colon in stead of a comma in the formula